# How to Check Payment Month wise

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a simple gim system payment reminder calculation part. I want to get the result of those who are not paid the amount of the current month whose people name need to be displayed. What I tried so far I attached below.

**Member** table

```
id   mno    pname       dob 
1   e001   john     1991.12.3
2   e002   steve     1987.11.3
3   e003   sunm     1986.11.31
4   e004   jeba      1981.1.3
```

**Payment** table

```
id   mno     paydate       amount     months
1   e001   2020-12-14      20000       12
```

Months table 12 means - **December** month I got the SQL code of current month `MONTH(getdate())`

I tried query like this

```
  SELECT Member.mno
    ,Member.pname
    ,payment.amount
FROM Member
LEFT JOIN payment ON Member.mno = payment.mno
WHERE payment.amount IS NULL
    AND payment.months = MONTH(getdate())
```

When I run the query I didn't get any result. I want to get the result of those who are not paid the amount of the current month whose people name need to be displayed. What was the problem with the above query?

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql", but the code will not run in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your condition from `WHERE` clause to `ON` clause as follows:

```
SELECT MEMBER.MNO,
       MEMBER.PNAME,
       PAYMENT.AMOUNT
  FROM MEMBER LEFT JOIN PAYMENT ON MEMBER.MNO = PAYMENT.MNO
                                AND PAYMENT.MONTHS = MONTH(GETDATE())
 WHERE PAYMENT.AMOUNT IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks sir. how to check paid people names

Comment: ` WHERE PAYMENT.AMOUNT IS NULL` --> ` WHERE PAYMENT.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL`  ------- OR convert your query to use INNER JOIN and omit the WHERE clause

Comment: thanks...........  sir. each month will this work successfully MONTH(GETDATE()) it will automattly changed month and check the payment

Comment: Yes, it will work for each month